# How to set the id of a set of textboxes using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm trying to rest the `ID` attribute of a set of text boxes when the delete button is pressed.

What I want to do is that when the delete button is pressed read the existing textboxes and rest there id's because when I delete items the ID's of the existing once keep the old ID values I want to rest this to match the error number value.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/s010dgvg)

```js
//Add and remove function for the error text boxes
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.addRow', function() {
    var div = $("<div />"),
      btnId = $("#stValue").val(); //Breaks the number from the ID using .match
    // btnId = $(this).data("bid").match(/\d+/);//Breaks the number from the ID using .match

    div.html(copy()); //Creates a new div container
    $('.error-Column').append(div); //Insert all the HTML into the new div

    $('#addRow_' + btnId).prop("disabled", true); //Disables the add button once clicked.
    resetErrorNo(); //Calls the reset function
  });

  //Remove the text filed from the list and resets the error number
  $(document).on('click', '.delRow', function() {
    if (confirm('Your sure you want to remove this?')) {
      var btnId = $("#stValue").val(), //Read the value of stValue
        btnId2 = btnId - 1; //Deduct 1 from the value to get the last ID

      for (var i = 0; i < btnId; i++) {
        $('.addRow').attr('id', 'addRow_' + i);
      }
      //Enables the 1st add button if the value equals 1
      if (btnId2 === 1) {
        $('#addRow_' + btnId2).prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#addRow_' + btnId).prop('disabled', false);
      }

      $(this).parent().remove(); //Remove the text row from the list.
      resetErrorNo(); //Calls the reset function
    }
  });
});

//Reset the entire error count number index
function resetErrorNo() {
  $(".errorCount").each(function(index, _this) {
    $(this).val(index + 1);
    $("#stValue").val(index + 1);
  });
}

//HTML function which will be called by the button click event for the add button
function copy() {
  var stNum = document.getElementById("stValue"),
    genNum = (document.getElementById("stValue").value - 1) + 2;

  // stNum.value = genNum;

  // language=HTML
  return '<input class="errorCount" size="1" value="' + genNum + '" style="margin-left: 2%" readonly/>\n' +
    '<select class="errorName" style="margin-left: 6%">\n' +
    '<option selected disabled>----- Select Error -----</option>\n' +
    '</select>\n' +
    '<input type="button" class="addRow" id="addRow_' + genNum + '" data-bid="addRow_' + genNum + '" value="Add" />\n' +
    '<input type="button" class="delRow" id="delRow_' + genNum + '" data-bid="delRow_' + genNum + '" value="Delete"/><br />'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jType-container">
  <div id="error-Add-Container">
    <div id="error-Column-Headings">
      Error Number<span style="margin-left: 8%">Error Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="error-Column">
      <input class="errorCount" size="1" value="1" style="margin-left: 2%" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1" id="stValue" />
      <select class="errorName" style="margin-left: 6%">
                             <option selected disabled>----- Select Error -----</option>
                         </select>
      <input type="button" data-bid="addRow_1" id="addRow_1" class="addRow" value="Add" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** I used the answer given by @Rory McCrossan and made some tweaks to get I wanted and ended up with the below code which is what I wanted to do in the first place.

```js
// Add and remove function for the error text boxes
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.addRow', function() {
    var $clone = $('.error-Column .error-container:first').clone().appendTo('.error-Column');
    $clone.find('select').val('');
    // $clone.find('input').val('');
    $('.addRow').prop('disabled', true).filter(':last').prop('disabled', false);
    resetErrorNo();
  }).on('click', '.delRow', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    if (confirm('Your sure you want to remove this?')) {
      $btn.closest('.error-container').remove();
      $('.addRow').prop('disabled', true).filter(':last').prop('disabled', false);
      resetErrorNo();
    }
  });
});

//Reset the entire error count number index
function resetErrorNo() {
  $(".errorCount").each(function(index, _this) {
    $(this).val(index + 1);
  });
}
```

```css
/*----- All the styling for the error input area start -----*/

#error-Column-Headings span {
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.errorCount {
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.errorName {
  margin-left: 6%;
}

.error-Column .error-container:nth-child(1) .delRow {
  display: none;
}

.error-Column .error-container:nth-child(1) .delRow {
  display: none;
}


/*----- All the styling for the error input area end -----*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jType-container">
  <div id="error-Add-Container">
    <div id="error-Column-Headings">
      Error Number<span>Error Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="error-Column">
      <div class="error-container">
        <input class="errorCount" size="1" value="1" style="margin-left: 2%" />
        <select class="errorName">
                                 <option selected disabled value="">----- Select Error -----</option>
                             </select>
        <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

hope this helps some one in the future.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use incremental `id` attributes? This can be made much simpler - and more DRY - by using common classes and DOM traversal

Comment: It's due to the way I've written the function I would love to learn how to simplify this more.

Comment: makes no sense to me, but here have fun `$("#ID"). removeAttr("id");`

Comment: I just want to reset the ID's with the correct value. My error number is correct just want to set the ID according to the error number. And I want keep the last `Add` button enabled no matter where I remove the line from.

Comment: I added an answer for you which should make the logic much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern which leads to a lot of unnecessary maintenance work - as you've discovered.

You can make your code much more DRY, not to mention more simple by simply cloning each row and using DOM traversal to find elements related to the buttons and add/delete them as needed. Try this:

```js
//Add and remove function for the error text boxes
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.addRow', function() {
    var $clone = $('.error-Column .error-container:first').clone().appendTo('.error-Column');
    $clone.find('select').val('');
    $('.addRow').prop('disabled', true).filter(':last').prop('disabled', false);
  }).on('click', '.delRow', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    if (confirm('Your sure you want to remove this?')) {
      $btn.closest('.error-container').remove();
      $('.addRow').prop('disabled', true).filter(':last').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#error-Column-Headings span {
  margin-left: 8%;
}
.errorCount { 
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.errorName {
  margin-left: 6%;
}
.error-Column .error-container:nth-child(1) .delRow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="jType-container">
  <div id="error-Add-Container">
    <div id="error-Column-Headings">
      Error Number <span>Error Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="error-Column">
      <div class="error-container">
        <select class="errorName">
          <option selected disabled value="">----- Select Error -----</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code looks much nicer and clean. I will make the changes but I would like ask you another thing in my code I was displaying the error number and was disabling the `Add` button (because the users here are very stupid). And when deleting I was re-enabling the last `Add` I know this is too much but can that be integrated in to your code.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me and I need to learn more about using DOM.